# Is it possible to install curl and composer with a command in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to install Curl and Composer in a command that executes in the command section of a docker-compose.yml ?
I don't want to build a new Image for that.

```
...
image: "customimage"
command: bash -c "apt update && apt -y upgrade
  && apt install curl
  && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer"
network_mode: bridge
ports:
  - "80:80"
  - "443:443"
links:
...
```

I tried this approach but it didn't work.

Comment: ...so you want to repeat this installation every single time the container restarts?  Putting it in a Dockerfile so that it only runs once seems like a much more straightforward approach; you can start `FROM` any image you want if you already have a customized base image.

Comment: so it should be like "FROM customimage" .. what if the image is on a remote server ?

Comment: `FROM registry.example.com/customimage` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should always try to do installation steps in a Dockerfile if you can.  Putting complex setup in a `docker-compose.yml` file is, well, complex, and anything in a Compose `command:` override will get repeated every time the container starts up.

The flip side of this is that you can start your Dockerfile `FROM` any image you want, even if it's hosted on some other registry; you're not limited to the core Docker Hub images.

So for what you show, you could write a basic Dockerfile like

```sh
FROM customimage # could be registry.example.com/remote-image:tag
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get upgrade -y \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
      curl
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer \
  | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
# ... more COPY and RUN commands ...
```

Then your `docker-compose.yml` file would just need to reference this image build

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  myapp:
    # building the local image downloads the base image,
    # does the OS-level package upgrades, and installs Composer
    build: .
    # use the default command: from the image CMD
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

There's not any particular downside to building a new image here.  You might consider building the image in your CI system as you would any other runnable artifact, but it's definitely possible to distribute this Dockerfile and Compose file together as instructions to build and run the image.